# Apache 2 UserDir for only one VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-userdir

Is it possible to enable the [UserDir Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html) for just one VirtualHost rather than have it on for all and then disable it (with "UserDir disable") for each VirtualHost you don't want it on?

I have tried by putting this inside a `<VirtualHost>` and comment out everything in the global config (/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdir.conf). No luck though.

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public.www
    UserDir disabled root

    <Directory /home/*/public.www>
            AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
            Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Deny from all
            </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You might have missed that `LoadModule userdir_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_userdir.so` is required, too.

Answer (score 4):

I only removed the `UserDir public.www` (in my case `UserDir public_html`) from the `userdir.conf`. Then I added that line to my site configurations where I wanted `mod_userdir` to be active.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName userdirs.example.com

        <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
                UserDir public_html
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This solution seems to work for me (ubuntu 14.04 lts).

Answer (score 0):

That should work, however there is a defect reported here:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44076

That prevents "normal" merging which is ironically what you're trying to avoid -- maybe because it's not working?

What exactly happens with your current configuration? Is mod_userdir loaded?

Comment: Agree with @covener. I just had it working.